# Как получить только папки доступные для чтения с помощью QDir::Filters?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5

Только начинаю осваиваться с Qt. Задумал сделать дерево каталогов, которое начинается с папки пользователя и отображает только папки. Немного полистав документацию написал такой код:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QFileSystemModel>
#include <QTreeView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget *wgt=new QWidget;
    QHBoxLayout *layer=new QHBoxLayout;
    QFileSystemModel *dirModel=new QFileSystemModel;
    QTreeView *tree = new QTreeView;

    dirModel->setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot|QDir::AllDirs);
    tree->setModel(dirModel);
    tree->setRootIndex(dirModel->setRootPath(QDir::homePath()+"/.."));
    layer->addWidget(tree);
    wgt->setLayout(layer);
    wgt->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Но так отображается папка lost+found, которая мне совсем не нужна.
[image: QDir::NoDotAndDotDot|QDir::AllDirs]

Изменил строчку с фильтром:

```
dirModel->setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot|QDir::AllDirs|QDir::Readable);
```

на что он мне выдал, на мой взгляд, что-то странное
[image: QDir::NoDotAndDotDot|QDir::AllDirs|QDir::Readable]

Как это исправить? Или может есть способ реализовать это лучше?

Comment: Мне не понятен Ваш вопрос, с одной стороны Вы сознательно переходите на ступень выше домашней директории, с другой Вас не устраивает, что нам том уровне отображаются другие папки, которые там есть. Какое у Вас желаемое поведение?

Comment: Хочу что бы содержимое домашней директории было свернуто в папку...любую. Меня не устраивает то что я вроде как устанавливаю фильтр по отображению только доступных для чтения папок, а он его как-то странно игнорит

Comment: Т.е. Вы хотите, чтобы у Вас отображалось только `sergey`? Т.е. только папка домашней директории, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: ну и все поддиректории, если есть способ просто завернуть содержимое QDir::homePath() в какую-то абстрактную папку, то это тоже подойдет

Comment: В сущности, если исходить из заголовка вопроса, то, по идее, код должен работать как надо: показывать лишь те папки, которые доступны для чтения. Если же нужно больше контроля над тем, что идёт от модели к отображению, нужно наследовать `QSortFilterProxyModel` и там уже реализовывать нужную логику.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению, код

```
dirModel->setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot|QDir::AllDirs|QDir::Readable);
```

на сегодняшний день работает некорректно. Вероятно у разрабов Qt иное виденье ситуации, поскольку ранее созданный [баг](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-19519) был закрыт по непонятной причине, хотя и легко воспроизводится вплоть до версии Qt5.4.1 включительно.

Возможным решением может быть либо переопределение фильтрации списка файлов и папок посредством `QSortFilterProxyModel` (как это предложил @ixSci в комментариях), либо реализация собственной модели со всем соответствующим функционалом и унаследованной от `QAbstractItemModel`.

Второе бывает предпочтительнее, поскольку оригинальный `QFileSystemModel` при первом обращении к новой папке (потом используется кеш) работает очень медленно, если последняя содержит десятки тысяч файлов.

Несмотря на то, что модель в целом функционирует многопоточно, медлительность чтения директорий большого состава связана с чтением иконок файлов, которые размещаются в `QIcon`, и который в свою очередь не может использоваться не в графическом потоке.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить путь к домашней директории просто используйте `QDir::homePath()`. Я имею в виду что содержимое папки пусть отображается в таблице а ее имя в заголовке.